# Repeat values in array n-times with different values for n

Tags: arrays, matlab, repeat

I'm having problems with the following task. I have a dummy array of zeros and 2 vectors of equal size. For example:

```
array1 = zeros(750,1);
vector1 = [1;3;5];
vector2 = [100;250;400];
```

I am looking to fill array1 as follows:

```
repeat element 1 in vector1 100 times
repeat element 2 in vector2 250 times
repeat element 3 in vector1 400 times
```

The resulting vector should have 7 rows and 1 column. I tried playing around with repmat but can't get it to output only 1 dimension. I also heard about bsxfun but I never end up with the data I need. I'm grateful for any useful suggestions.

I have Matlab 2013, so I'm not able to use the fancy function repelem that I found might be useful.

Comment: So you want  to have the 100 first values of `array1` equals to 1, 250 next values equals to 3, 400 next values equals to 5, and the other values equal to 0?

Comment: I think he made a typo and means to put only `vector1` elements into `array1`, then the duplicate is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
array1(1:100) = vector1(1);
array1(101:350) = vector2(2);
array1(351:750)=vector1(3);
```

though why the total length is `2850` is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
    vector1 = [1;3;5];
    vector2 = [100;250;400];
    temp = linspace(1,sum(vector2),sum(vector2))';
    array1 = zeros(size(temp));

    for ii = 1:length(vector2)
        array1 = array1 + (temp <= sum(vector2(1:ii)) & not(array1))*vector1(ii);
    end
    clear temp ii
```

Comment: This is just a slow and memory-consuming version of @Benoit_11 's marked duplicate.

Comment: I thought vector1 and vector2 should be some kind of parameter.